# Fluentd Openstack Log Regex format

Tags: ruby, regex, openstack, fluentd

I am trying to parse the logs from all the OpenStack services and send it to S3 in JSON.

I am able to get parse the logs with this multiline format.

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/nova/nova-api.log
  tag nova
  format multiline
  format_firstline /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\.\d{3,6})? [^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]*/
  format1 /(?<DateTime>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(\.\d{3,6})? (?<pid>[^ ]*) (?<loglevel>[^ ]*) (?<class>[^ ]*) (\[(?<context>[^\]]*)\])? (?<message>.*)/
  time_format %F %T.%L
</source>
```

which parses the logs of this type

```
2018-09-05 12:34:01.451 3212169 INFO nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server [req-0f15c395-5962-4a14-ba7a-730f86d6eb7e f1ab53782de846798920050941f3bcff f5d0c8e495cd4793814f8b979693ac17 - default default] 192.168.1.1 "GET /v2.1/os-services HTTP/1.1" status: 200 len: 1435 time: 0.0372221
```

and this type

```
2018-09-05 12:34:33.631 2813186 INFO nova.api.openstack.placement.requestlog [req-d4573763-4521-419f-a4ba-c489a7e17ea9 fba548d81cd6480b90940a89e00f4133 6ba1bbedb40c411e9482128150886ba6 - default default] 192.168.1.1 "DELETE /allocations/196db945-0089-40ae-8108-a950fb453296" status: 204 len: 0 microversion: 1.0
AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
2018-09-05 12:34:37.737 2813187 INFO nova.api.openstack.placement.requestlog [req-08b8b3e4-6981-4cd4-b90b-c922b7002b28 fba548d81cd6480b90940a89e00f4133 6ba1bbedb40c411e9482128150886ba6 - default default] 192.168.1.1 "GET /allocation_candidates?limit=1000&resources=CUSTOM_Z270_A%3A1" status: 200 len: 473 microversion: 1.17
```

into this

[Fluentular Demo](http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/parse?regexp=%28%3F%3CDateTime%3E%5Cd%7B4%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D+%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%28%5C.%5Cd%7B3%2C6%7D%29%3F+%28%3F%3Cpid%3E%5B%5E+%5D*%29+%28%3F%3Cloglevel%3E%5B%5E+%5D*%29+%28%3F%3Cclass%3E%5B%5E+%5D*%29+%28%5C%5B%28%3F%3Ccontext%3E%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D*%29%5C%5D%29%3F+%28%3F%3Cmessage%3E.*%29&input=2018-09-05+12%3A34%3A33.631+2813186+INFO+nova.api.openstack.placement.requestlog+%5Breq-d4573763-4521-419f-a4ba-c489a7e17ea9+fba548d81cd6480b90940a89e00f4133+6ba1bbedb40c411e9482128150886ba6+-+default+default%5D+192.168.1.1+%22DELETE+%2Fallocations%2F196db945-0089-40ae-8108-a950fb453296%22+status%3A+204+len%3A+0+microversion%3A+1.0%0D%0AAH01626%3A+authorization+result+of+Require+all+granted%3A+granted%0D%0AAH01626%3A+authorization+result+of+%3CRequireAny%3E%3A+granted%0D%0AAH01626%3A+authorization+result+of+Require+all+granted%3A+granted%0D%0AAH01626%3A+authorization+result+of+%3CRequireAny%3E%3A+granted%0D%0A2018-09-05+12%3A34%3A37.737+2813187+INFO+nova.api.openstack.placement.requestlog+%5Breq-08b8b3e4-6981-4cd4-b90b-c922b7002b28+fba548d81cd6480b90940a89e00f4133+6ba1bbedb40c411e9482128150886ba6+-+default+default%5D+192.168.1.1+%22GET+%2Fallocation_candidates%3Flimit%3D1000%26resources%3DCUSTOM_Z270_A%253A1%22+status%3A+200+len%3A+473+microversion%3A+1.17&time_format=)

i am trying to get the ip, request_type path and statu using this

```
(?<DateTime>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(\.\d{3,6})? (?<pid>[^ ]*) (?<loglevel>[^ ]*) (?<class>[^ ]*) (\[(?<context>[^\]]*)\]) (?<ip>[[\d+\.]*) \"(?<http_request_type>[^ \"]+) (?<http_request_path>[^\"]+)\" status\: (?<http_status_code>[^ ]+) (?<message>.*)
```

see demo here.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vpwoCb/1)

which works perfectly in regex101, but the td-agent fails with this error

```
[error]: config error file="/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf" error_class=Fluent::ConfigError error="Invalid regexp in format1: premature end of char-class: /(?<DateTime>\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})(\\.\\d{3,6})? (?<pid>[^ ]*) (?<loglevel>[^ ]*) (?<class>[^ ]*) (\\[(?<context>[^\\]]*)\\]) (?<ip>[[\\d+\\.]*) \\\"(?<http_request_type>[^ \\\"]+) (?<http_request_path>[^\\\"]+)\\\" status\\: (?<http_status_code>[^ ]+) (?<message>.*)/m
```

Comment: it looks like escaping issue, can you show the actual code?

Comment: This is the pattern that is failing <source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/nova/nova-api.log
  tag nova
  format multiline
  format_firstline /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\.\d{3,6})? [^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]*/
  format1 /(?<DateTime>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(\.\d{3,6})? (?<pid>[^ ]*) (?<loglevel>[^ ]*) (?<class>[^ ]*) (\[(?<context>[^\]]*)\]) (?<ip>[[\d+\.]*) \"(?<http_request_type>[^ \"]+) (?<http_request_path>[^\"]+)\" status\: (?<http_status_code>[^ ]+) (?<message>.*)/
  time_format %F %T.%L
</source>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was an extra square brace in match group ip. The correct pattern is.

```
(?<DateTime>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(\.\d{3,6})? (?<pid>[^ ]*) (?<loglevel>[^ ]*) (?<class>[^ ]*) (\[(?<context>[^\]]*)\])? (?<ip>[\d+\.]*) \"(?<http_request_type>[^ \"]+) (?<http_request_path>[^\"]+)\" status\: (?<http_status_code>[^ ]+) (?<message>.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to escape your xml online, like here: https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-escape.html or replace `@` to `&amp;`

Comment: i don't have any XML data to be parsed, its just log data, like this 2018-09-05 12:34:01.451 3212169 INFO nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server [req-0f15c395-5962-4a14-ba7a-730f86d6eb7e f1ab53782de846798920050941f3bcff f5d0c8e495cd4793814f8b979693ac17 - default default] 192.168.1.1 "GET /v2.1/os-services HTTP/1.1" status: 200 len: 1435 time: 0.0372221